# Unable to extract find/extract all tags from html file using Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to identify each and every HTML tag. 
I have a regular expression **that just identities a tag**.
But I am unable to extract or identify these tags.

I know Beautiful Soup can be used to extract HTML data, but I wish to use these HTML tags in a stack to do other operations.

Here is what I have tried-

```
import re
the_data = '''
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<p>Some text updates here.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
'''
reg_exp_match = '''<((?=!\-\-)!\-\-[\s\S]*\-\-|((?=\?)\?[\s\S]*\?|((?=\/)\/[^.\-\d][^\/\]'"[!#$%&()*+,;<=>?@^`{|}~ ]*|[^.\-\d][^\/\]'"[!#$%&()*+,;<=>?@^`{|}~ ]*(?:\s[^.\-\d][^\/\]'"[!#$%&()*+,;<=>?@^`{|}~ ]*(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'"<\s]*))?)*)\s?\/?))> '''
pattern = re.compile(reg_exp_match)

x = re.findall(pattern, the_data)
print(x)
```

I am unable to extract the tags with the help of this regular expression. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @ForceBru , With due respect , I have mentioned that I wish to just identify tags and nothing inside the HTML tags. I am well aware that BeautifulSoup can be used for the same.

Comment: I just think that using BeautifulSoup is way easier than writing this regex. Like, the regexes in your post are already pretty huge, hard to read (and thus error prone) and probably even harder to debug. Moreover, once you manage to write this regex, it'll likely become a kind of magical piece of code that only the chosen ones can understand. Using BeautifulSoup, however, is much simpler and much more understandable. This doesn't mean you _mustn't_ write a regex to extract tags - it's just my opinion.

Comment: Could you give us the expected output from your example?

Comment: <\/?([^\/>\s]+).*> try this regex with your code, remove the \/? if you only want to match opening tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't need to use such a complicated regular expression. This regular expression `<[^/>][^>]*>` helps identify all tags.